# Publish Maven build to Artifactory from Jenkins

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, artifactory

I have a build setup in Jenkins, which compiles a simple Git hosted Maven project into a jar and publishes the jar into Artifactory.

1. How can I setup the build job to tag the sources which were used for the build with e.g. a build number (or similar), in order to later be able to identify which sources went exactly into this particular build. This build tag should also be visible in git's remote repository, not just in the local version on the Jenkins build server.
2. Ideally I'd also like to package this "build tag" into the jar (I suppose in a file inside the jar) so I can always correlate the jar to which source files were used to create this jar.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [Jenkins Artifactory Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin) or the [Maven Artifactory Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin).

Both generate a [`BuildInfo` metadata](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration) that include the information you need and much, much more. All this information is attached to the artifacts and make the artifacts traceble without need to embed this info in the filenames or into the archives themselves.

Please take some time to watch [this screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxtQThl8B-8). It explains in detail what you can get and why it's important.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see the BuildInfo metadata in Artifactory which is great information. The only weakness is that when I look at the server where the code jar is deployed I have no correlation back to Artifactory, In specific I don't necessarily know if last week's jar is deployed or the one from the week before, especially when the code is still in the SNAPSHOT stage where the file name doesn't necessarily get appended by the build number.

Comment: That's a great comment! Since Artifactory uses checksum-based storage, search by checksum is the easiest and the fastest way to take any file and correlate it with the tons of metadata you have for it. Just run `md5 filename`, go to checksum search, from there to the tree browser on the result, build tab, and boom! you know exactly how this file was created!

Answer (score 2):

> 1. How can I setup the build job to tag the sources which were used for the build with e.g. a build number (or similar), in order to later be able to identify which sources went exactly into this particular build. This build tag should also be visible in git's remote repository, not just in the local version on the Jenkins build server.

This can be done using the standard Git plugin. Underneath where you configure the repository to clone, click "Add" on "Additional Behaviours", and choose "Create a tag for every build"

[image: Creating a tag on every build]

> 2. Ideally I'd also like to package this "build tag" into the jar (I suppose in a file inside the jar) so I can always correlate the jar to which source files were used to create this jar.

This tag should then be available as an environment variable during the build steps (I think it's called GIT_TAG) - you can have your existing build step put this value into the file or add a pre-build "Execute Shell" step which does something like this:

```
$ echo $GIT_TAG > git.tag
```

Comment: Thanks! Does the "Create a tag for every build" option also push the tag back to the git remote server (origin) or are there extra steps to take to push the tag?

Comment: I believe so (I can't see a use for it otherwise), but I can't check easily now - try it out and see what happens.

Comment: I tried and the "Create tag for every build" did not push the tag back to origin. I ended up using the Git Publisher as a Post-build action to create and push the tag instead of the "Create tag for every build" Pre Step. Unfortunately there isn't a lot of up-to-date documentation about the Git Publisher so it took me a while to figure out how to configure it.